# Disable USB mouse wake up for any USB port

Tags: windows-10, mouse, power-management

I know I can prevent a mouse from waking the system from sleep by unchecking "Allow this device to wake the computer". The problem is that if I plug the USB receiver of the wirelss mouse into a different USB port, that setting is lost. I have to uncheck it again.

Is there anyway to prevent the mouse from waking up the computer no matter which USB port the receiver is plugged into?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Powercfg.exe tool to disable a device from waking the computer from a sleep state.

**Usage**

```
powercfg -devicedisablewake devicename
```

*devicename* specifies a device retrieved by using the `powercfg -devicequery wake_armed` command.

Check the following link for detailed information about Powercfg.exe tool: [Powercfg Command-Line Options](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: I also needed this to stop my USB wireless mouse from waking my machine. No amount of disabling the mouse wake in device manager would work.

Comment: @MerseyViking I had the same problem as you describe and I finally found out that I had to disable my keyboard from waking the computer as well for it to work for the mouse. See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-power/windows-10-cannot-disable-the-mouse-from-waking/706340c2-1fcc-4cd0-b747-c736d8a31b34.