# Is there a way to disable mouse movements when computer is locked?

Tags: windows-10

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMpAA.jpg]

When the PC is locked, it goes to password mode and the monitor turns off. The problem is that sometimes my mouse detects movement and it makes the monitor turn on. Is there a way to disable the mouse if the computer is locked?

Comment: The correct terminology is lock the pc, similar as WIN+L. Is your mouse wired or wireless?

Comment: @LPChip It's wired

Comment: It should be called "Lock mode", not "block mode"

Comment: Somewhat related: https://superuser.com/q/1192586/513819 and https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-power/windows-10-cannot-disable-the-mouse-from-waking/706340c2-1fcc-4cd0-b747-c736d8a31b34